# IE6 and IE7 do not handle margins properly on elements with height property

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

I have an h2 within a div. Both of them have borders. The h2 has a height attribute and a margin. When I view my page in IE6, IE7, or IE8 compatibility view, the h2 is all the way at the top of the div as if the margin is 0. However, if I view it in any other browser, the h2 has some space above it like I would expect.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and what to do about it. I am trying to make the page render in IE like it does in Firefox, without setting the height to auto.

Here is a page you can test to show the problem. Try viewing it in IE6 or IE7, then try it in any other browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<title>CSS margin test</title>
<style type="text/css">
div {
    border: solid blue 1px}
h2 {
    height:33px; margin:80px 0 0; border: solid red 1px}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h2>test</h2>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "zoom: 1" CSS property to force proper layout in IE. This is a common solution for IE bugs. Putting it on the div fixes your issue:

```
div {
    border: solid blue 1px;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

A general-purpose fix is also possible:

```
* {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Google "hasLayout" for more info.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I have read lots of articles about zoom and hasLayout, but somehow it didn't occur to me that it would fix this bug.

Comment: Is this exaclty what you were looking for? Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted, so other people may benefit from it directly!

Comment: Note that giving hasLayout to all elements with the wildcard selector can cause other bugs. I only ever give hasLayout when an element is misbehaving.